# On minimising form,the drawings disappears in c#

Tags: c#, graphics, visual-studio-2008

I currently working with c# PictureBox and facing one problem.I have made handsfree drawing in picture box.It draws nicely on the picture box.But when I minimizing the form and reload it again then the drawings disappear.
Any one can suggest remedy for this problem…
Thanks…

Comment: You should draw on a bitmap, and put it in the `pictureBox1.Image` property.

Comment: I just applied this code but no change ...                                                       
                                                                                                                       
                Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(ImagepictureBox.Image);

Comment: Because you should do `var bmp = new Bitmap(width, height); pictureBox1.Image = bmp;` and draw on the `bmp` bitmap.